# How to implement TornadoFX WebEngine Callback in Kotlin

Tags: javafx, kotlin, javafx-webengine, tornadofx

I am using Kotlin TornadoFX to create a browser. When I implement WebEngine setCreatePopupHandler, I get an error:

> e: surfing\src\surfing.kt: (76, 13): Modifier 'override' is not
>   applicable to 'local function'
>
> e: surfing\src\surfing.kt: (76, 13): Expected a value of type WebEngine!

I referenced this Java code using JavaFX:

```
webEngine.setCreatePopupHandler(
            new Callback<PopupFeatures, WebEngine>() {
                @Override
                public WebEngine call(PopupFeatures config) {
                    smallView.setFontScale(0.8);
                    if (!toolBar.getChildren().contains(smallView)) {
                        toolBar.getChildren().add(smallView);
                    }
                return smallView.getEngine();
            }
    });
```

Translated into Kotlin to use TornadoFX:

```
var wv = webview() 
val br = wv.getEngine()
br.setCreatePopupHandler(Callback<PopupFeatures, WebEngine>() {
            override fun call(pf: PopupFeatures): WebEngine {
                var smallView = webview() 
                val stage = Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY)
                stage.setScene(Scene(smallView))
                stage.show()
                val engine = smallView.getEngine()
                return engine
            }
        })
```

I have been searching for a long time on the internet, but I didn't find anything. Please can somebody help me fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there :) To create an anonymous class much the same way you do in Java, you need to use the `object` keyword in front of the class statement:

`br.createPopupHandler = object : Callback<PopupFeatures, WebEngine> {`

However, Kotlin allows you to turn SAM types into lambdas. You can also utilize the property access pattern and immutable values to clean up the code a little. Here is a the code rewritten and Kotlinified:

```
val wv = webview()
val br = wv.engine
br.setCreatePopupHandler {
    val smallView = webview()
    val stage = Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY)
    stage.scene = Scene(smallView)
    stage.show()
    smallView.engine
}
```

I haven't really evaluated what you're doing here or if that's a good idea, so only take my advice on the syntax :)

Comment: First I'm very surprised tornadoFX developer to answer my question. thank you so much. This problem let me from tornadoFX ver 1.5.7 change to ver1.7.5 , result ouccer other ver problem so I change back ver1.5.7 and try your advice method compile it. BUILD SUCCESSFUL solved my problem. thank you again :)

Comment: Great! If you're having problems upgrading, it's probably because you forgot to change jvmTarget to 1.8. See the instructions on the 1.7.1 release notes page: https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/releases/tag/v1.7.1